# Aggregate subtotal and a taxableSubTotal in same aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data model with Packages that each have an array of Product documents.
Each product document has a price and an isTaxable:boolean field

I can do the aggregate on getting the subtotal for each package (product.price $sum), but I can't figure out how to "also" get the taxSubtotal in the same aggreation, which would consist of getting a separate sum of the product.price where product.isTaxable is true

This is what the package record looks like:

```
// Package
   {
    _id: 1,
    packTitle: "Package 1",
    productCategory: {_id:90, label:"Clothing"},
    products: [
          {   _id:500, 
             "prodTitle": "Product 1",
             "price": 2.99,
             "isTaxable" : true
          },
          {   _id:501, 
             "prodTitle": "Product 2",
             "price": 4.99,
             "isTaxable" : false
          },
          {   _id:502, 
             "prodTitle": "Product 3",
             "price": 6.99,
             "isTaxable" : true
          },
          {   _id:503, 
             "prodTitle": "Product 4",
             "price": 10.99,
             "isTaxable" : false
          }
    ]
}
```

I'm able to get the subTotal with :

```
db.prodPacks.aggregate([
    {$match: { "productCategory._id": {$in:[90]} }}
  , {$unwind: '$products'}
  , {$group: {
            '_id': {'packId':'$_id', 'packTitle':'$packTitle'},  
            'packSubtotal': {$sum: '$products.price' },
            'products':{'$push':'$products.title'}
            }
    }

])
```

I have the packSubtotal, I would like to also get a taxableSubtotal (a sum of the product.price where isTaxable is true, in the same aggregation, if possible.

I know I could do a separate aggregation with a match on isTaxable and then get that subtotal and manually add them together, but I was curious if there was a way to do it all in one aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a sum of the "product.price" where "isTaxable" is `true` you need to use the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)  conditional aggregation operator.

```js
db.packages.aggregate([ 
    { "$match": { "productCategory._id": 90 } }, 
    { "$unwind": "$products" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "packId": "$_id", 
            "packTitle": "$packTitle" 
        },
        "packSubtotal": { "$sum": "$products.price" }, 
        "products": { "$push": "$products.prodTitle" }, 
        "taxableSubtotal": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [ "$products.isTaxable", "$products.price", 0 ] 
            } 
        } 
    }}
])
```